# Data from associative array in Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I have an associative array and made a datadump of it (See picture)
[image]

With smarty I want the pw_pro_Code to be visible in a select list

```
{foreach from=$clientProjects item=Array}
  {foreach from=$Array item=pw_pro_Code}
    <option value="{$pw_pro_Code}">{$pw_pro_Code}</option>
  {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

But this shows me both pw_pro_code and pw_wc_InstanceId in list. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please do not post code as image.

Comment: I did it because it was a datadump and therefore not formatted (all text on a single line) but won't do it again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single loop would work -

```
{foreach from=$clientProjects item=Array}
    <option value="{$Array.pw_pro_Code}">{$Array.pw_pro_Code}</option>
{/foreach}
```

Comment: You are a genius :)

Comment: Hehe.. Thanks.. I would suggest some more learning about the loops. :)